# Jetpack Joyride device sync

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Is it possible to sync between an android device and a Windows 8 PC?  I have a lot of progress on a lot of games on my Droid Razr M, but I just got a new all-in-one, which is great for my daughter.  I want to put my Jetpack Joyride progress on there, especially, but I don't think it's possible.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, as the platforms use different and incompatible means of storing application data.